# Where can i find a simple resource on how to Migrate windows server AD to Azure cloud

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, migration

I want to migrate my Organization's Windows Server AD to Azure cloud (Azure Active directory domain services)

I can't seem to find any good documentation from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can migrate your on-prem physical servers to Azure as per the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/migrate/tutorial-prepare-physical)

Azure AD Domain services and Azure Active directory services are two different things in Azure.

You will get more details from the [document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/what-are-the-differences-between-azure-active-directory-and/ba-p/917392).